# Parsing raw .pcap flow in python

Tags: python, pcap, tcpdump, packet-sniffers

Let me first describe the architecture of my project. I am dumping packets from a router by using `tcpdump ... | nc <vm_addr> 1111` which translates them to a virtual machine, which has lots and lots of memory for this purpose.

On the virtual machine I am planning to read the packets by using my python script and then sort the packets for example by the port they using.

I am wondering which is the best way to do it, because most of python pcap libraries can read from file, but not from socket or file handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [pypcap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcap)?

`$ sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev`

`$ pip install pypcap`

A socket can read and write as a file can. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574865/socket-read-with-pcap). With bursty traffic it may be a good idea to implement a loop and some (StringIO or file) buffering nevertheless.